# Solve equation $1-3^{x-1}+2^{\frac{x}{2}}-2^{\frac{x}{2}}3^{\frac{x-1}{2}}=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For $x \in R$, solve $$1-3^{x-1}+2^{\frac{x}{2}}-2^{\frac{x}{2}}3^{\frac{x-1}{2}}=0$$.
I've tried to notate $a=2^{\frac{x}{2}}, b=3^{\frac{x}{2}}$, but gotten nowhere. I've also tried to divide by $2^{\frac{x}{2}}\cdot3^{\frac{x}{2}}$, but the result is more or less the säme as the initial equation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set $2^{x/2}=b, 3^{(x-1)/2}=a$

$$0=1-a^2+b-ab=(1-a)(1+a)+b(1-a)=(1-a)(1+a+b)$$

For real $x, a,b>0\implies a+b+1>1\ne0$

Now $3^{(x-1)/2}=a=1\implies(x-1)/2=0$

Comment: @LazyLee, Thanks